Text stroke is not filled in one place in 3
With 3, text stroke is not filled in one place:

The font I use is Fredoka, bold.
I tried using other fonts, but this one suits my project very well.
Is it a CSS issue or a font issue? What should I do to fix it?


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@700&display=swap');

body {
  font-size: 150px;
}
p {
  color: lime;
  font-family: "Fredoka";
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke: #000 0.15em;
  paint-order: stroke fill;
}
<p>Cash: 123$</p>




I do not see the problem, using IOS Safari. What browser, OS and device are you using?

Unfortunately the text-stroke implementations are flawed. See "Text Stroke (-webkit-text-stroke) css Problem" – you may try a text-shadow workaround.
